# Saving multipart JAX-RS (Resteasy) upload into a JPA (Hibernate) blob

Tags: hibernate, jpa, file-upload, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm trying to implement a way to upload large files (hundreds of megabytes potentially). I'm already aware that a naive implementation will cause heap overflows, so I'm looking for an implementation that makes proper use of multipart uploads and that doesn't store the whole file into an array of bytes.

How can I save a multipart upload into a database blob? Most snippets show how to receive a multipart upload and persist into a file or how to load the whole file into an array of bytes, put into a JPA entity and then persist.

Is there a way to make this process fully asynchronous? If not, what is the proper data type to be annotated into the JPA entity? What is the proper way to construct this type out of the JAX-RS invocation? When and where will the synchronization occur?